# Parallel Requests with AJAX & Guzzle 6

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, guzzle, guzzle6

I'm trying to do concurrent parallel AJAX requests to PHP pages that use Guzzle to call data. However, each AJAX request is waiting for the previous request to complete before continuing.

How can I do parallel requests?

I've tried Guzzle Pool and Batch, but that doesn't really work for my use case.

EDIT: This is the code I have now:

```html
// Create pool of requests
$generator = function (array $urls) {
    global $client;
    global $apiClientKey;
    global $apiSecretKey;
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        yield function() use ($client, $url, $apiClientKey, $apiSecretKey) {
     return $client->getAsync($url, ['auth' => [$apiClientKey, $apiSecretKey]]);
        };
    }
};
 
// Process pool of requests
$pool = new Pool($client, $generator($urls), [
    'concurrency' => 7,
    'fulfilled' => function ($response) {
     return $response->getBody();
    },
    'rejected' => function ($exception) {
     $exceptionMessage = explode("\n", $exception->getMessage());
        print_r($exceptionMessage[1]);
    },
]);
 
// Initiate the transfers and create a promise
$promise = $pool->promise();
 
// Force the pool of requests to complete.
$promise->wait();
```

Comment: Could you please post the code you currently have? Have you tried to use promises?

Comment: Do you have `ext-curl` installed and enabled in your PHP installation? Guzzle is able to make parallel queries only with cURL.